# Passing 'this' object to the 'then' callback function of $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I am having problems passing  'this' object to the 'then' callback function of $http service as shown below

```
var Product = function(){
    this.name = "putty";
    this.price = 760;
    $http.post(url, data).then.call(this, function(){
        this.saved = true;
    });
};
```

When I inspect 'this' object in the statement this.saved = true, I realise that it is pointing to the global object and not to an instance of Product as expected since I have "then.call(this, function(){..." instead of "then(this, function(){..." as can be seen in my code. Any help please???

Comment: Your problem is that `.call` is binding `this` to `then`, not to the function that's being passed as an argument to `then`. What would work is `.then(function(){ this.saved = true; }.bind(this);`

Comment: @DRobinson Possibly make that an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using `then.call(this, function(){});` you're calling the `then` function as `this`, but that will not affect the `this` value of the actual callback function that you are passing.

If you want to bind `this` to the callback, you can use `bind`:

```
$http.post(url, data).then(function(){
    this.saved = true;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Won't `this` have the scope of the callback function? Rather than the `Product` object?

Comment: No, the bind will create a copy of that callback function where this is the Product.

Answer (score -1):

Assign a var to this and use that var instead. See below

```
var Product = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.name = "putty";
    self.price = 760;
    $http.post(url, data).then(function(response){
        self.saved = true;
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to re-assign it:

```
var Product = function(){
    this.name = "putty";
    this.price = 760,
    self = this;
    $http.post(url, data).then.call(this, function(){
        self.saved = true;
    });
};
```

Comment: @PSL removed it, forgot to remove it from the original code example

Comment: All three of you guys are totally missing the point. He's using `.call` for a reason. His confusing is why `.call` is seemingly not invoking the function with his expected proper `this`. The confusing stems from `call` being used on the wrong function (it's correctly setting `this`, but doing so to the `then` function, not his callback.