# How to use props or state in promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a some question about how to access props or state in promise.
I have username password input and one button.The actionClickSignIn function work when i click button.Then i click button it show error

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

i want to know how to access props or state in UserAuth. Thankyou

my constructor

```
this.actionClickSignIn = this.actionClickSignIn.bind(this);
```

my function , UserAuth is using axois

```
actionClickSignIn() {

  let {username,password} = this.state;
     this.props.setName("John")  // --- > It work !!!!
  UserAuth(username,password).then(function(res){
     this.props.setName(res.data.user.name)  //---> not work !!!!
     this.state.isLogin = true
  }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
  });
}
```

and reder function

```
<Button  type="button" onClick={this.actionClickSignIn}> Sign In</Button>
```

Comment: I think it's not duplicate, it's the opposite. OP should use arrow function syntax to pass context into the function passed as the first argument to "then".

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin, you are right. The target dupe post has the reverse problem. I missed that. Here is a relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772222/2030321

Comment: In other words @devnext: replace `then(function(res){` with `then(res => {` or `then((res) => {`.

Comment: @Chris it’s not duplicate because state and props work in actionClickSignIn

Comment: or perhaps  `}).catch` change to  `}.bind(this)).catch`

Comment: Perhaps a more appropriate duplicate would be https://stackoverflow.com/q/30268550/125981 with this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/30268723/125981

Comment: Here is some background that may assist others as well http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/

Comment: Note the net effect that @Chris suggests is to use a "fat arrow" function which captures the "this" of the containing scope. some doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this